# Raw data transfer over USB (Interrupt Endpoint)

Tags: java, android, usb, data-transfer

I have a USB card reader that I am trying to program, instead of focusing a text field and getting raw data input injected to the field. I want to be able to listen for the data. I read the USB host docs in the Android API and followed a few tutorials on SO as well. I think I have everything set up, except I am confused on the listening for data part.

I have tried a loop to see if I can get the IN and OUT endpoints of my device, but I only get 1 returned, leading me to think it's a unidirectional device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

private UsbManager manager;
private HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList;
private Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator;
private UsbDevice device;
private UsbInterface intf;
private UsbEndpoint endpoint;
private UsbDeviceConnection con;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        device = deviceIterator.next();

        intf = device.getInterface(0);
        endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);


        con = manager.openDevice(device);
        if(null == con) {
            Log.e("FAIL: ", "Couldn't connect to device");
        }
        else {
            con.claimInterface(intf, true);
        }
    }

    setDevice(device);

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void setDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    this.device = device;
    if(device.getInterfaceCount() != 1) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ", "Could not find interface!");
        return;
    }

    if(intf.getEndpointCount() != 1) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ", "Could not find endpoint!");
        return;
    }

    if(endpoint.getType() != UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ", "Endpoint is not type interrupt");
        return;
    }

    if(device != null) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[11];
    //i've tried multiple variations of this and still no luck.
    int resp = con.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT, 00, 00, 0, buffer, 11, 0);

    Log.i("RESPONSE: ", "" + resp);

  }

}
```

**device_filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Should be the IDs for MagTek SCRA Scanner -->
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="0801" product-id="1" class="0" subclass="0" protocol="0"/>
    <usb-device vendor-id="2049" product-id="1" class="0" subclass="0" protocol="0"/>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="valhala.io.usbdbg" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Edit: It turns out my device uses an INTERRUPT endpoint.
How would I send a command to get the card data? Plus, how can I implement it in a way where it's not constantly listening and sleeping on the thread? Would an AsyncTask work?

I was using https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/samples/USB/MissileLauncher/src/com/android/missilelauncher/MissileLauncherActivity.java

as a reference, but I am not sure where they get their numbers for the `controlTransfer()` command.

**EDIT: Sadly the card reader I am using has absolutely no identifying marks on it, but based on the vendor ID, i believe this is actually the correct doc. I will keep the 2nd one posted for reference..**

`Vendor ID: 0801`
`Product ID: 0001`
https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875206.pdf

```
 public int controlTransfer (int requestType, int request, int value, 
 int index, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)
```

So I tried the following:

`con.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT, 0, 0x00, 0, buffer, 11, 0)` 
which returns a -1, it also doesn't put anything in the buffer.

EDIT: I got it "working" on a different computer. But when I send get commands all responses say it was successful but return no data. The window on the left is the software that "came" with the device, which lets you reprogram SOME stuff, but the MagTek program does nothing, even though they are allegedly the vendor according to the device descriptors. Am I just SOL with this scanner in particular?

[image: wow]

Comment: here's the doc for the HID version: https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875191.pdf